# how to speed up a slow code using "vector<>"?

Tags: visual-c++

Currently, I use the vector container for an algorithm. 
The algorithm results excellent values, however, the running time is a big problem. So I tried to use other data structures like new and delete in some test-programs. The running times are 200 times less than using vector.

Eventually, my question is: is there any way to change the code by using new, so that I don't have to change the whole code which has more than 10,000 lines, because I use the vector-methods very often.

However, time needed to access an element like in the test-program might be the biggest problem.

```
struct SOME_ELEMENTS
{
int a;
float b;
vector<int> c;
};

void function_1(vector<SOME_ELEMENTS> &elements, int number)
{
    vector<SOME_ELEMENTS> temp_elements;
    vector<SOME_ELEMENTS> best_elements = elements;

    while (true)
    {
        temp_elements = elements
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            temp_elements[i].c.push_back(i);
            //change temp_elements in many other way
            //calculate a value depending on temp_elements

            if (true)
            {
                best_elements = temp_elements;
            }

        }

        if(true)
        {
             elements = best_elements;
        }
        //termination_criterium
    }

}

void main()
{

    int no;
    vector<SOME_ELEMENTS> a;
    //set values for a and no
    function_1(a, no);


    _getch();
}
```

Here an example where using vector is 200 times slower:

```
void main()
    {
    int no = 100000;
    int runnings = 10000000;

    //int *big_vect = new int[no];
    vector<int> big_vect(no);

    int a = 1;

    big_vect[no - 1] = 1;

    clock_t start_time, end_time, computing_time;

    start_time = clock();


    for (int i = 0; i < runnings; i++)
    {
        big_vect[no - 1] = big_vect[no - 1] + 1;

    }

    end_time = clock();
    computing_time = end_time - start_time;

    _getch();
}
```

In advance, thanks for any help!

Comment: [Reserving memory](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) might be a good start.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but do you have any idea how to reduce the access time, which should be the problem in the test program?

Comment: Once you populated a vector, access time (using the indexing operator `[]`) is almost as good as accessing a normal array.

Comment: As for the second program, it's a simple loop that only accesses and modifies a single element in the vector, so that single entry would be in the closest cache all through the loop which should make it pretty fast as no memory access needs to be made really. The compiler might even be able to optimize the loop away completely.

Comment: When I compile your second program (with optimization), it always gives me 0 time elapsed, probably because the whole loop is eliminated as dead code.  Timing without optimization is pretty meaningless, as the optimization dominates.   With optimization, vector-based and array-based code should be close in speed.

Comment: Following your comment, I expected both to need the same computing time. However, define big_vect with "new" only needed a computing time of 20 sek/1000 and "vector" 3900 sek/1000.

Comment: Have you tried compiling with optimization enabled?

Comment: Wow, thanks! Now, both versions need the same computing time.

Comment: Really, thanks again for the optimization enabled tip. Now, the computing times are about 250 times faster!